# Hay algo en mi código PHP que no funciona bien

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una DB con una columna única de username, cuando el usuario ingresa, paso una variable de sesión para poder hacer un registro por pasos. Probando, uso un nombre que no existe en la DB y así y todo me devuelve que ya existe, mi código de insert:

```
    <?php

include('config.php'); 
$username=mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['nombreJugador']);
$_SESSION['username'][1]=mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['nombreJugador']);
$_SESSION['password'][2]=mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['password']);
$_SESSION['email'][3]=mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email']);
$_SESSION['sexo'][4]=mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['sexo']);
$_SESSION['nacionalidad'][5]=mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['nacionalidad']);
$_SESSION['edad'][6]=mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['edadPersonaje']);

function rand_string() {
    $chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!?{}()*+-/=%&#@|";  
    $size = strlen( $chars );
    for( $i = 0; $i < 16; $i++ ) {
        $salt .= $chars[ rand( 0, $size - 1 ) ];
    }
    return $salt;
}

$salt = rand_string();
$hash1 = hash('sha256', $password . $salt); 



$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM jugadores WHERE username='$username'";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
if ($result != 0)
{
  header('Location: registrarse.php?error=1');
}
else {
    $sql="INSERT INTO jugadores(username,password, salt,email,pSexo,pNacionalidad, pEdad, pRegistro, pCertificacionAprobada) VALUES('$username','$hash1', '$salt', '$email','$sexo', '$nacionalidad', '$edad', '1', '0')";
    if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
           header('Location: registrarse.php?success=1');
        } else {
          // header('Location: registrarse.php?no=1');  
          echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);         
        } 
    //header('Location: registrarse2.php');
}   

mysqli_close($link);


?>
```

Siempre me devuelve a donde estaba con la variable que le pasé aunque cuando hago un count con el mismo nombre que intenté registrar, me tira que el valor de rows que hay es 0, o sea que debería hacer el insert.
¿Qué tengo mal?

Edit: La variable de nombreJugador aparece dos veces por que pensé que la variable de sesión no se estaba guardando, pero todavía no lo comprobé.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[mysqli_query($query)](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php) retorna un valor `booleano` , `FALSE` sí ocurrió algún error y un objeto [mysqli-result](http://php.net/manual/es/class.mysqli-result.php) si la consulta se ejecuto correctamente.*(SELECT, SHOW , DESCRIBE)*

```
if ($result != 0) /* Siempre será 1 , dado que no muestra error */
```

Para validar que existe el usuario o no , podrías acceder al número de filas que devuelve su consulta. [mysqli-result.num-rows](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) *variando un poco su consulta*

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM jugadores WHERE username='$username'";
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
   $count = $result->num_rows;
   if ($count == 0) header('Location: registrarse.php?error=1');
   else { ...}

   $result->close();
}
```

Comment: Por eso, no está bien como lo usé yo?

Comment: @Primus la segunda parte de mi respuesta  ,verificar ...

Comment: Ahi probé, solo que cambie que el error sea si $count > 0, porque si da 1 significa que el usuario existe. Así y todo sigue diciendome que username existe cuando la base de datos me devuelve un 0.

Comment: Genial, ahora parece funcionar, me había olvidado que había borrado la variable $username y dejé las de sesión. Aunque ahora por algún motivo parecen no cargar bien, voy a probar imprimirlas en un echo. Están bien planteadas las variables de sesión? (le saqué los array)

Comment: Es un tema basado en opiniones , en mi caso opino que no es necesario Usar variables de `SESSION`  para recibir valores por `POST.`

Comment: El problema es que esa es la parte del registro 1, yo pensaba enviar un query al final de la tercer parte ya con todas las variables juntas en lugar de enviar varias por cada paso. Principalmente para evitar errores

Answer (score 0):

El problema creo yo que esta el momento de usar la variable $username, esa variable no esta declarada, tal vez cuando se ejecuta el PHP la deja en blanco y por eso te devuelte algo, cambialo por esto:

```
 $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM jugadores WHERE username='".$_SESSION['username'][1]."';";
```

Me cuentas que tal...

Comment: No funcionó, sigue enviandome como si existiera el username. Le saqué los array a las variables de sesion porque creo que no eran necesarias.

Comment: Impre con un echo esta variable y dime que sucede: $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM jugadores WHERE username='$username'";

Comment: Modifique un poco el código, comenté todo lo que no andaba para que no moleste y el $username devuelve la variable que tiene que devolver (que es el usuario inexistente)